# How to parse the data returned from a ajax function within jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to return some data from my server. What I get is a data string object.

How can I parse this html object, so that I only get a part of this returned data?

Comment: Too little information. Try to return the string as JSON from the server and use `JSON.parse(stringData)`

Comment: I return html, and try to find a element by id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the `dataType`. What kind of data do you expect to receive and which `dataType` do you specify in the jQuery `.ajax()` method?

If you specfiy `json` for instance, jQuery (since version 1.3.2 I guess) will try to parse the received data into a Javascript object. But in general, you can just modify the received data yourself with all `String methods` available.

```
$.ajax({
    url:  '...',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        //var part = data.substring(0,8);
        $(data).find('#my_element');
    }
});
```

This would take only the first 8 characters from the received data. Another way is to apply a `regular expression` on your received data. All on you.

**edit**

Based on your comment: If your transfer a valid HTML chunk of data, you can just wrap that data into a jQuery contructor and use all methods available there, for instance `.find()`

Comment: data.find() gives me a error... how can I convert data into a jquery object then?

Comment: I think you should just remove the dataType line, if it is HTML - it properbly yells at you because it don't treat the returned result as HTML. Or maybe the dataType sould be 'html' instead.

Comment: Ah I see i use js format for every ajax request. How to change or remove the dataType line?

Comment: I've found a way now: $('#buffer').html(data); this way the html gets written in a jquery object which is parsable...